# "Faking" Template class method specialization with enable_if

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, enable-if

I wonder if the SFINAE principle/enable_if's can be used to "fake" the partial specialization of the class template method. For example, given the class template `Foo` in which two versions of `Foo::bar` are defined. I'd like to enable one and disable the other if `T2 = int` (for example) and vice-versa.

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct Foo
{
    void bar();
};

// Enable if T2 != int (disable otherwise)
template<typename T1, typename T2>
void Foo<T1,T2>::bar()
{
}

// Enable if T2 == int (disable otherwise)
template<typename T1, typename T2>
void Foo<T1,T2>::bar()
{
}
```

PS: boost enable_if's preferred please. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Edited.] You can produce different overloads by typifying boolean values:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct Foo
{
    void bar_impl(std::true_type);
    void bar_impl(std::false_type);

    void bar() { bar_impl(std::is_same<T2, int>()); }
};
```

Comment: It works, thanks. Unfortunately, this method will probably fail `bar` is specialized for an additional type e.g. `T2 = char`. Also an extra cost is incurred if the compiler does not inline the implementations.

Comment: Oops. Unfortunately, it doesn't work if T2 is a non-type parameter e.g. elements of an enum. Sadly, this is the case that I need it for.

Comment: @Olumide: You can "typify" values with the same template trick that `true` is typified into `std::true_type` and then overload on that.